# aggregate fitness data from multiple users in the same web app using the Google Fit REST API

Tags: google-fitness-api

I am currently working on a web application which is supposed to track multiple users and monitor their health parameters (pulse, number of steps, location etc). What I've currently thought about is having an administration interface which aggregates all data sent by the registered users. I want to use the Google Fit REST API.

Is it possible to fetch the workout data of all registered/active users in the same screen, being authenticated only with the admin account? Does Google provide such feature? I know there is something similar for the Gmail API. I am looking for some kind of live tracking solution, but using the specified API.

Answer (score 0):

To collect and store users' information, users must first provide their consent via the consent screen. After that, your app will be required to undergo a security assessment and its price will based on your scopes; I strongly advise migrating to Health Connect.

https://developer.android.com/guide/health-and-fitness/health-connect-guidelines/migrate/migration-guide